# How to find rank of this linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra

> $T : \mathbb R^4 \to \mathbb R^4$ is a linear transformation.
>   
> And there exists $v \in \mathbb R^4$ s.t $v, T(v), T(T(v))$ is linearly independent and $T(T(T(v)))=0$ 
> Find rank $T$

What only I can figure out from given sentence was only $T(T(v)) \in $ N($T$)$\cap$R($T$)

Please give me any hint or advice, not a solution.

Comment: Must the answer be unique? It seems to me there are two possibilities...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A complete answer that establishes that there is not a single answer to your problem (as suspected by @Miguel Atencia): the rank may be 2 or 3.

First of all, vector $v$ cannot be $0$, because ... $0,0$ and $0$ are not independent...

Since $T^3v=0$, $v \in Ker(T^3)$ with $v \neq 0$, thus $det(T^3)=0$, thus $det(T)=0$, implying $rank(T)<4$.

On the other hand, $rank(T)\geq2$, because $Tv$ and $T(Tv)$ belong to the range space of $T$ and are independent.

Now 2 examples: one can check that conditions $v,Tv,T(Tv)$ independent and $T^3v=0$ can be fulfilled with either a rank 3 matrix:

$$T=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 & 1 & 1\\0 & 0 & 1 & 1\\0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix} \ \ \text{and} \ \ v=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\1\\0 \end{bmatrix} \ \rightarrow \ Tv=\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\0\\0 \end{bmatrix} \ T^2v=\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\\0 \end{bmatrix} \  \ T^3v=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\\0 \end{bmatrix}$$

or a rank 2 matrix:

$$T=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 1 & 1\\0 & 0 & 1 & 1\\0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix} \ \ \text{and} \ \ v=\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\0\\1 \end{bmatrix} \ \rightarrow \ Tv=\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\\0 \end{bmatrix} \ T^2v=\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\0\\0 \end{bmatrix} \  \ T^3v=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\\0 \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: From $\;T^3v=0\;$ it follows that $\;\text{rank}\,T\le 3\;$, and we can even get $\;\text{rank}\,T\ge2\;$ , yet the question hasn't been answered yet (even after $\;\det T=0\;$)

Comment: @Joanpemo Of course, the question has not been answered, because I have respected the will of Luke lee not to give a full answer but a hint.

Comment: I gave a complete answer because one can loose a lot of time on problems that are ill posed: in your case it should not have been  "find (THE) rank" but "find the possible values for the rank" (+ maybe "and display matrices that fulfill the conditions").

Comment: Very nice answer. +1

Comment: @JeanMarie I'm not living in English culture, so I translated on my self and made a mistake about what U said. Sorry for confusing.

Comment: No problem.  I am happy that you have found convenient the solution I  have proposed.

Answer (score 3):

What does $T$ look like as a matrix in the basis $\{T^2v,Tv,v,u\}$? can you put a lower bound on the rank? *Hint* $$A=[c_1 c_2 \dots c_n] \Rightarrow Ae_i = c_i$$